# GetWindowTextLength выдает размер 0

Tags: c#

Всем привет, буду рад любой помощи или совету. Если есть альтернатива тому, что я хочу сделать, то так же с радостью выслушаю.

Данный кусок кода проверяет открылось ли уже окно и какое.

```
            int counter = 0;
            while (counter != curRun.Count)
            {
                counter = 0;
                foreach (var elem in curRun)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(GetWindowTextLength(elem.Value.MainWindowHandle));
                    if (GetWindowTextLength(elem.Value.MainWindowHandle) > 5)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        Console.WriteLine(counter);
                    }
                }
            }
```

В моей задаче стоит дождаться открытия окна steam с логином, но перед ним иногда вылезает окно с обновлением. Окно обновления называется - "Steam" и `GetWindowTextLength` определяет длину окна как 5 (что логично), однако когда окно обновления закрывается и открывается окно логина, которое называется "Вход в Steam", оно определяется как 0 символов.

- curRun - словарь содержащий String:Process
- Решил не использовать FindWindow тк у юзера может отличаться язык от моего и названия будут разные

Comment: А чего вы делаете, так особо и не написали, точней не написали зачем это все. Если делаете автоматизацию клиента стима, то как по мне это самое бредовое решение, которое можно только придумать, ведь стим "открыт" вплоть до генерации 2fa ключей и прочей приблуды, все делается простыми POST запросами, а вы вдруг автоматизируете окно....

Comment: @EvgeniyZ автоматизирую клиентское приложение Steam. Данный кусок кода ожидает открытия окна стима для ввода 2fa кода.

Comment: Авторизация клиентского приложения делается вообще без стим клиента и чего-либо еще, чисто Web с его REST API запросами. Вообще не кажется странным писать приложение, которое ждет другое приложение? Как по мне, это очень странное поведение. Но в любом случае, вам виднее, видите так свой проект - дерзайте)

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов, когда GetWindowTextLength возвращает 0, всего 2:

> If the window has no text, the return value is zero.
>
> Function failure is indicated by a return value of zero and a GetLastError result that is nonzero.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowtextlengthw